Nextjs vs React for using with Capacitor or Cordova
Can someone please help me- I need to write an mvp on wheather with just reactjs oooor with nextjs - but keeping in mind that I need to convert it into mobile app in two weeks(do not ask why:) can please tell is there any concerns on wheather I should choose nextjs over just plain react and vice versa?? And what is better Cordova or Capacitor Thank you!!
There is no much documentation on this topic

If you want to use nextjs and capacitor, be aware that it will only work with output: "export" in your next config file, which adds a lot of limitations. Check out the Static Export page in nextjs docs for the list of limitations. If your app content is available at build time and doesn't need to handle dynamic data, this may work for you. If you want a mobile app with a backend server and/or that connects to a database and is built from the same codebase as a web app, nextjs + capacitor will not work, and I would go with React + Vite SPA and integrating with capacitor that way.

Thank you so much, it actually was much easier to go with react native since it was not that hard to learn after all, but I did go with react + vite and actually created a PWA using vite:))
